# e.hostname is not a function Angular Production Build (OS Package)

Tags: angular, npm, package, hostname, ng-build

I have facing against an issue provoked by an `npm package` which I previouly installed to get the `hostname and ip address` in my `angular project`, everything is ok in `dev mode` but when I build it to get the `production files` it doesn't work, I have debugged my project and I noticed that everything fails when I use the method to get the hostname.
Nowadays what I'm doing is printing in console the next code.

I declared the next variable.

```
declare var require: any;
```

And I'm using the next code in my `ngOnInit()`

```
const os = require('os');
console.log(os.hostname());
```

In dev mode it works, but in production mode is fails throwinf the next error.

[image]

I my `package.json` I have the package `os` in my dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
   "os": "^0.1.1",
   ...
}
```

Does anyone know why this happen?

Comment: Angular is front-end library and `os` seems to be a NodeJS library. Are you sure you're using the right one / using it correctly ?

Comment: Also, `require` is not advised in Typescript, use `import from` syntax instead.

Comment: **Maryannah** thaks for your answer, currently I'm using that package in my front-end, so Am I wrong if I use it to get client hostname in my front? or Is there another way to get hostname (pc name) using Angular or js?. Regarding your advice I already tried using `import instead require` Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then yes, you misuse it. You can't get the host name in a front ent project. It's only a backend feature.

Comment: You can't. That's a security breach. The browser doesn't have access to it.